# Google Cloud configure YAML file for a website

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Good day, I have a website that contains only HTML files, JS and plugins like jQuery, Datatables, etc.

As I configure the YAML file to tell my JavaScript files are in one route, the CSS in another, I have a layered route where there are HTML files and a route called appends where all the plugins are.

The problem is that it sends an error when you want to load the JavaScript files

I hope you can help me, I send you sample of my path.

```
2017-10-24  15:05    <DIR>          appends
2017-10-24  15:05    <DIR>          css
2017-10-24  15:07    <DIR>          img
2017-09-14  08:31             5,759 index.html
2017-01-31  12:57            13,254 index_under.html
2017-11-01  12:33    <DIR>          js
2017-10-27  14:22    <DIR>          layers
```

My app.yaml file is this:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: img/favicon.ico
  upload: img/favicon.ico
  mime_type: image/x-icon
- url: /css/
  static_dir: static
- url: /img
  static_dir: static
- url: /js
  static_dir: static
- url: /appends
  static_dir: appends
- url: /.*
script: index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a dispatch.yaml file:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/dispatchref

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/164356) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable.